# how to do login authentication using gmail and facebook in jsp and servlets?

Tags: facebook, jsp, authentication, servlets, gmail-pop

Can you please provide any suggestion for login using `Gmail and Facebook` authentication 
from my website using jsp and servlets?????

```
Is there any plugin to do this concept?
```

Please provide any links or samples.

Comment: Use the (javascript) APIs that Google and Facebook provide on their developer sites.

Comment: @david Thnks.I did google authentication by using javascript APIs.but it shows popup window.In that popup window only that process had done.I dont wnt that pop up window..Can you give any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved using Social Login ,

As **[Janrain](http://janrain.com/product/social-login/)** says how to do it to your website

SignUp [**here**](http://janrain.com/product/social-login/) and you would be asked to embed a piece of code to your application and it would create the API call.

It is so simple once you start , as they provide free products for basic usage.

Hope this helps!!